# WP_Query for attachments without duplicating post_parent and displaying tagged image

Tags: wp-query, loop, attachments

I've tagged a number of media uploads on my site with the various products' names which are featured in them. The goal is to get a list of the posts which have been tagged with each product name, but without duplicating the parent post.

Ideally I would be able to display one of the attachments from Loop 1 (which actually displays the tagged product) with a link to its post_parent, but I have only been able to get the post thumbnail from Loop 2 (these don't always show the product)  to work up to this point.

My brain is fried. Any thoughts?

Loop 1 - querying for attachments with a particular tag.

```
$media_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'products',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $product_tag
                    )
                )
            );
$media_items = new WP_Query($media_args); 

if ($media_items->have_posts()) {
    $parent = array();
    while ($media_items->have_posts()) : $media_items->the_post();
        // getting the post_parent and cleaning to weed out duplicates
        $parent[] = get_post_field('post_parent', $post->ID);
        $parent_clean = array_unique($parent);
    endwhile;
}
```

Loop 2 - querying for the list of unique posts

```
$product_post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $parent_clean
    );
$product_posts = new WP_Query($product_post_args);

if ($product_posts->have_posts()) { ?>
   while ($product_posts->have_posts()) : $product_posts->the_post();

   $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'browse' );

   echo $img[0];

   endwhile;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it another look with some fresh eyes, I decided to add a third loop within Loop 2 and not have it working as desired:

```
$media_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'products',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $product_tag
                )
            )
        );

// Loop 1 - To get the images with the desired tags

$media_items = new WP_Query($media_args); 

if ($media_items->have_posts()) {
    $parent = array();
    while ($media_items->have_posts()) : $media_items->the_post();

        // getting the post_parent and cleaning to weed out duplicates

        $parent[] = get_post_field('post_parent', $post->ID);
        $parent_clean = array_unique($parent);
    endwhile;
}

$product_post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $parent_clean
);

// Loop 2 - Get the posts which have the images from Loop 1 as attachments without duplicating the same post

$product_posts = new WP_Query($product_post_args);

if ($product_posts->have_posts()) {
   while ($product_posts->have_posts()) : $product_posts->the_post();

       $product_image_args = array(
           'post_type' => 'attachment',
           'posts_per_page' => 1,
           'post_parent' => $post->ID,
           'tax_query' => array(
               array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'productcats',
                   'field' => 'term_id',
                   'terms' => $product_tag
                   )
               )
       );

       // Loop 3 - To get the first attachment with the desired tag for each post

       $product_images = new WP_Query($product_image_args);

       while ($product_images->have_posts()) : $product_images->the_post();               
           $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, 'browse' );
           echo $img[0];
       endwhile;

  endwhile;
}
```